# Why is ffmpeg and vlc able run RTSP stream but gstreamer is unable to?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp

I have a RTSP server streaming out h264 video. Both ffmpeg (`ffplay uri`)and vlc are able to stream the video but gstreamer is unable to.

Below is the output of gstreamer when `gst-play uri` is launched:

`ERROR Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in. for rtsp://---- ERROR debug information: ../gst/playback/gsturidecodebin.c(1028): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: no suitable plugins found: ../gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.c(7691): gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams_start (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source Reached end of play list.`

Am I missing certain gstreamer plugins or is my RTSP video stream set up wrongly?

Appreciate any advice! Thank you!

Comment: For sure gst-play should be able to receive an RTSP stream, decode and display if your platform is able and has correct plugins installed for that. As error message seems to say, there might be something wrong with your gstreamer installation. You may provide more details about your platform/OS and a way for someone having same system to reproduce.

Comment: I get the following error when running: `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://--- --gst-debug=3`:

`0:00:00.186498400 11384 0x7fffdc2d2580 ERROR                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4536:gst_rtspsrc_stream_configure_udp_sinks:<rtspsrc0> no UDP sink element found`

which is weird because my rtsp stream is tcp

Comment: What give: `gst-inspect-1.0 udpsink` and `gst-inspect-1.0 -b`

Comment: Have checked the following and all seems to be in check! However am now facing a different issue: `multiudpsink gstmultiudpsink.c:1229:gst_multiudpsink_configure_client:<udpsink1> error: Invalid address family (got 23)`